# How to create an import/export script using Node.JS?

Tags: node.js

I'm looking to import/export a list of files in a directory through an index.js file in the same directory.

For example, I have 2 files in a directory: admin.js and user.js and I am looking to require and exporting them in the in the index.js like so

```
module.exports = {
  admin: require("./admin"),
  users: require("./users"),
};
```

The script I have come up with looks like this but it is not working and giving me an error

```
fs.readdirSync(__dirname, (files) => {
  files.forEach((file) => {
    module.exports[file] = require(`./${file}`);
  });
});
```

How can I improve this script to make it work?

Thank you!

[Update - 2022 December 18]

Found a solution based off of sequelize models/index.js, this will pretty much require and export your files and folders, feel free to use and modify

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const basename = path.basename(__filename)
const controllers = {}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((folder) => {
    return folder.indexOf('.') !== 0 && folder !== basename
  })
  .forEach((folder) => {
    const controller = require(path.join(__dirname, folder))
    controllers[controller.name] = controller
  })

module.exports = controllers
```

Comment: ***not working and giving me an error***.  Please provide the exact error message and describe what isn't working.  This is general advice for any problem you post about here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey, you can add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 1):

`fs.readdirSync()` does NOT accept a callback.  It directly returns the result:

```
const files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
for (let file of files) {
    module.exports[file] = require(`./${file}`);
}
```

Note, the future of the Javascript language is using `import` and `export` with statically declared module names instead of `require()`and `module.exports` and this structure will generally not work with the newer way of doing things.  So, if you expect to eventually move to the newer ESM modules, you may not want to bake in this type of architecture.

There is a dynamic import in ESM modules, but it's asynchronous (returns a promise that you have to wait for).

Also, note that this will attempt to reload your `index.js` file containing this code.  That's might not be harmful, but may not be your intention.

Comment: I attempted your solution but got this error
```throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))```
```TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined```

Here is how I am importing it in the other file, 
```const { admin, users } = require("./router");```

Comment: @R41313IT - That error does not come from the code in my answer or your question.  It comes from something further upstream/downstream and it also depends upon what is  being exported in the actual module files you're loading.  We can't figure out what is causing that without seeing ALL the code involved.  That particular error means you are passing a non-function to `router.use()`.